# MS Access: Two ComboBoxes Populate TextBox

Tags: combobox

I currently have a form that has two combo boxes. One has names  and the other has hour type (ie regular “rg” and overtime “ot”). I would like that depending on the name selection and hour type selection it would auto populate a certain labor rate as that would defer depending on name and if they worked overtime or regular time. I know how to autopopulate a text box using one combo box but was not sure how to go about it with two. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub ComboBoxNames_AfterUpdate()
if isnull(me.ComboBoxRate) or me.ComboBoxRate = "" then
    exit sub
else
    me.textbox1 = "Enter the value you want the text box to display"
end if
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBoxRate_AfterUpdate()
if isnull(me.ComboBoxNames) or me.ComboBoxNames = "" then
    exit sub
else
    me.textbox1 = "Enter the value you want the text box to display"
end if
End Sub
```